# Stuck at deployNodes when trying to run the basic cordapp-example

Tags: corda

### The problem

I'm trying to run the [cordapp-example](https://github.com/corda/samples-java) ("Basic" folder), but when I try to do that I get stuck at the [deployNodes instruction](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/tutorial-cordapp.html#deploying-the-cordapp-locally) by the following top error:

```
$ ./gradlew deployNodes
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :workflows-java:deployNodes
Running Cordform task
Deleting C:\Users\auriaad\Desktop\JavaTest\samples-java\Basic\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes
Bootstrapping local test network in C:\Users\auriaad\Desktop\JavaTest\samples-java\Basic\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes
Generating node directory for Notary
Generating node directory for PartyA
Generating node directory for PartyB
Generating node directory for PartyC
2020-12-09 13:45:08,526 Execution worker for ':' Thread 4 INFO Cannot initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager
    at org.apache.
```

The first time it was showing off errors continuously (at "executing" stage, 38%) and it almost crashed my machine because of resources consumption; so I stopped the process and made it run again, getting the aforementioned error.

### What I tried

- I checked I set the environment correctly, it appeared so.
- I reinstalled the JDK and the JRE, hotspot version.
- I deleted the folder of the sample and cloned it again

### Additional info

```
$ java -version  
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_275-b01)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

- Windows 10
- JDK 8
- IntelliJ
- Gradle 5.6.4

I can't spot the problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was related to OpenJDK by Adopt.
After substituting it with the Zulu (supported) one, everything worked smoothly and the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

- Download Zulu Java 8 JDK https://www.azul.com/downloads/
- Set the path of JAVA_HOME to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home' with the command 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home' (DO THIS IN YOUR IDEA TERMINAL)
- Close Intellij and open again, go to file -> project structure -> select zulu as the SDK on the dropdown menu

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).